# Two-Dimensional Array using Templates

Tags: c++, templates, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to implement a dynamic array:

```
template <typename Item>
class Array {
private:
    Item *_array;
    int _size;
public:
    Array();
    Array(int size);
    Item& operator[](int index);
};

template <typename Item>
Array<Item>::Array() {
    Array(5);
}

template <typename Item>
Array<Item>::Array(int size) {
    _size = size;
    _array = new Item [size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << i << " " << _array[i] << " " << &_array[i] << endl;
}

template <class Item>
Item& Array<Item>::operator[](int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index > _size-1)
        cout << "this: " << this << ". Index out of range" << endl;

    return _array[index];
}
```

When used like this, it works as expected, i.e. prints `5`:

```
Array< int > testArray(5);
testArray[0] = 5;
cout << testArray[0] << endl;
```

However, I would like to use the class for a two-dimensional dynamic array. I thought that the following would just magically work and print 5...

```
Array< Array<int> > testArray(5);
testArray[0][0] = 5;
cout << testArray[0][0] << endl;
```

...but it does not work. It crashes when I try to set the value at [0][0]. The debugger shows me that `this` has `_size` set to 0 and `_array` to `NULL`. `this` at that point points to the first element of the `_array` of the last created Array instance.

One of the things I don't get is when the "inner" array calls its constructor. Stepping through the code, I see that `Array(int size)` is called once and `Array()` five times. I would like to create the inner array with a specific size, but using `Array< Array<int>(10) > testArray(5)` does not compile.

Could you provide me with some insight on this? It seems I could not quite wrap my head around templates yet...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot chain constructor calls in C++. Your first constructor implementation does nothing, so the 5 instances contained in the parent `Array` end up being uninitialized, resulting in undefined behavior.

To fix, you can either add a default value to the `size` parameter of the other constructor, or factor out the initialization logic in a separate (private) function, and call it from both constructors.

**EDIT**: The reason why the first constructor does nothing is that the line

```
Array(5)
```

does not call the constructor of the current instance, but instead allocates a new (unnamed) temporary `Array` instance, which is immediately destructed at the end of the line.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that you could not chain constructor calls! I now created a private function and it now works, but only with the size specified in the default constructor. Any ideas on how to create the inner array with a dynamic size?

Comment: If you're using C++11 **and** the outer array size is statically known, you can use an initializer list to provide initializers for all inner arrays. Anyway, I forgot to write that in my answer, but unless this is anything other than an exercise, the real solution is to use `std::vector`.

Comment: Yes, it's just an exercise. Could you tell me what you mean with "initializer list"? using `_array = new Item [size](size);` does not compile for me.

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Initializer_lists) for example.

Answer (score 3):

Use default value for constructor to call it without argument i.e. `Array(int index = 5);`

Please check this:
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.3

Can one constructor of a class call another constructor of the same class to initialize the this object?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call another ctor from your default ctor . If you want to have a default value you can combine the two into one.

```
template <typename Item>
Array<Item>::Array(int size = 5) {
    _size = size;
    _array = new Item [size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << i << " " << _array[i] << " " << &_array[i] << endl;
}
```

However if you still prefer to have the two ctor then you can move the implementation to a private _setup function that can be used from both like this.

```
template <typename Item>
Array<Item>::Array() {
    _setup(5);
}

template <typename Item>
Array<Item>::Array(int size) {
    _setup(size);
}

template <typename Item>
void Array<Item>::_setup(int size) {
    _size = size;
    _array = new Item [size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << i << " " << _array[i] << " " << &_array[i] << endl;
}
```

**Edited to remove invalid initializer for newed array.**

Comment: Adding (size) after the [] brackets does not compile for me...?

Comment: So it would seem I have gotten ahead of myself and forgot you cannot specify an initializer for arrays with the new statement. Perhaps using a vector rather than a pointer to an array would be ideal. I suspect this if for class and you cannot use any existing stl.